# Why does my Flask chatbot code take a very long time to execute and does not respond at the 'app.run()' step?

Tags: flask, vectorization, chatbot, chunking, nlp-question-answering

very long time consumed in executing the code and with no response

I've tried running the below code many times which is for creating a web application for a custom Q&A chatbot feeded by a custom data, but unfortunately the execution doesn't response every-time at the step of `app.run()`

```py
import PyPDF2

def extract_text_from_pdf(file_path):
    text = ""
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
        for page in reader.pages:
            text += page.extract_text()
    return text
def chunk_text(text, chunk_size):
    chunks = []
    words = text.split()
    for i in range(0, len(words), chunk_size):
        chunk = " ".join(words[i:i+chunk_size])
        chunks.append(chunk)
    return chunks
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import numpy as np

def build_vector_store(chunks):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(chunks)
    vector_store = {
        "chunks": chunks,
        "vectorizer": vectorizer,
        "vectors": vectors.toarray()
    }
    return vector_store

def retrieve_most_similar_chunks(query, vector_store, top_k=5):
    query_vector = vector_store["vectorizer"].transform([query]).toarray()
    similarities = cosine_similarity(query_vector, vector_store["vectors"]).flatten()
    most_similar_indices = np.argpartition(similarities, -top_k)[-top_k:]
    return [vector_store["chunks"][i] for i in most_similar_indices]
def create_chatbot(pdf_file):
    text = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_file)
  
    chunk_size = 500  # Adjust the chunk size as needed
    chunks = chunk_text(text, chunk_size)

    vector_store = build_vector_store(chunks)

    def chatbot(query):
        similar_chunks = retrieve_most_similar_chunks(query, vector_store)
        response = "I'm sorry, I couldn't find an answer to your question."
        if similar_chunks:
            response = "Here is some relevant information:\n\n"
            response += "\n\n".join(similar_chunks)
        return response

    return chatbot
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
chatbot = create_chatbot("/content/AP 107.pdf")  # Provide the PDF file path

@app.route("/api/chatbot", methods=["POST"])
def api_chatbot():
    data = request.get_json()
    query = data["query"]
    response = chatbot(query)
    return jsonify({"response": response})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```